# Creating rings with wave texture?

Tags: texturing, procedural

Trying to make a procedural metal texture. I used this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43221/how-to-align-wave-texture-perfectly/81888) to help me make the blue wave texture wrap around the object but I also want to have the red wave texture form in rings so that it would match the direction of the blue wave texture.
[image]

By forming rings I mean it would look like the section of the sphere here:
[image]

So the wave texture would move in this direction:
[image]

I've tried messing around with the rotation and location of the wave but I can't get it to move in the direction I want. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Wave texture alignment]

You can use the "Object" output of the Texture Coordinate node, together with the "Rings" type wave texture.

Comment: thanks! I'm really happy with how it looks now :D